# how can I prevent the login screen to be shown after suspending?

Tags: 10.04, login-screen

I mean the following screen:

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 10.04. I tried various solutions from previous posts but none of them helped .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah you have to do like , open your system settings and open screensaver settings and uncheck the password option for screensaver .[image]